# lateral view outer explode hive to snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

What's equivalent to this hive query in snowflake?

The lateral view outer explode is supposed to create a column with 'a' and 'b' for each distinct record set.

```
select
     o.*,
     domain
   from
     (
       select distinct group, program, track
       from my_snowflake_table
     ) o
     lateral view outer explode(
       array(
         'a',
         'b'
       )
     ) wt as domain
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select distinct x."GROUP", x.program, x.track, z.value
from my_snowflake_table as x, lateral SPLIT_TO_TABLE('a.b', '.') as z
```

Answer (score 0):

The example uses a static array('a', 'b') so it could be translated using CROSS JOIN:

```
select distinct x."GROUP", x.program, x.track, z.domain
from my_snowflake_table as x
CROSS JOIN (VALUES ('a'), ('b')) z(domain);
```